# How to make vectors do bound checking in vs code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vector

I have had only used visual studio till now and it automatically did the vector's bound checking for me. Due to my recent switch to linux, I had been forced to use VS Code instead and realized that it does no bound checking for me meaning I can create a vector of size 5 and access it's 237th element and it will give no runtime error.

I tried searching out a lot on the internet but there is no satisfactory response about how to get this functionality in vs code. I have seen that vs code also does not throw warnings and runtime errors compared to visual studio in general. So can i get it using any extension or something. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Using VS Code, the global replace command, replace all instances of `[]` on vectors with `at()`.  Try a single file first, then apply the replacement to all files in your project.

Comment: *I tried searching out a lot on the internet but there is no satisfactory response about how to get this functionality in vs code* -- This has nothing to do with VS-Code -- It has everything to do with the compiler's runtime library.  The Visual Studio C++ compiler has a debug runtime that does the automatic checking for out-of-bounds accesses.  Unless the compiler you're using for Linux (probably g++) has a similar debug version of their runtime, then you just have to start using `at()` instead of `[ ]` when accessing the array elements.

Comment: Use libstdc++ debug mode, compile with the compiler flag `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html.

Comment: You can also compile with the command-line parameter `-fsanitize=address` to get notified of illegal memory access.

Comment: Be aware that `at()` will throw an exception for an out of bounds access, so be prepared to catch that.  You won't get a nice friendly popup like you do with MSVC.

Comment: If you don't want exceptions but instead want to find the bugs leading up to the out of bounds access, compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and run your program.